# Multiple BigQuery subselects for new columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a one-to-many relationship of a business' name to a ZIP code, due to multiple industry codes matching that business for a given ZIP code. A separate table contains households by ZIP codes. To sum households with ZIP codes as rows and a given business as a column while deduplicating households matching the same ZIP code in multiple rows (to avoid over-counting households), I query

```
SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(SumHouseholds1) AS Company1  
FROM (  
    SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds1  
    FROM Business  
    JOIN Location  
    ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
    WHERE DBAName='Company1'  
GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households)  
GROUP BY ZIPCode
```

for output like this:

---

ZIPCode   Company1
    10001      17007
    10003      54084

When I try adding additional columns (Company2, Company3, etc.) to the original SELECT statement:

```
SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(SumHouseholds1) AS Company1  
FROM (  
    SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds1  
    FROM Business  
    JOIN Location  
    ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
    WHERE DBAName='Company1'  
GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households),  
SUM(SumHouseholds2) AS Company2  
FROM (  
    SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds2  
    FROM Business  
    JOIN Location  
    ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
    WHERE DBAName='Company2'  
GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households)
GROUP BY ZIPCode
```

I get an Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" error.

Comment: Can you explain two things: `1`. Why you are using here SUM () OVER() `2`. Why you are grouping by Households; `Overall` - your code so far doesn't make any sense to me! I would recommend presenting examples of your input and desired output as well as some logic details.

Comment: Thanks - I added sample output. the SUM() OVER() is to deduplicate Households matching the same ZIPCode value, and the GROUP BY for Households can't be omitted.

Comment: How many companies/columns you expect to have? Is it just very few or hundreds and more? Solution will depend on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming your initial code really works for you - below will fix issue with second query

```
SELECT 
  c1.ZIPCode AS ZIPCode, 
  c1.Company1 AS Company1, 
  c2.Company2 AS Company2, 
  c3.Company3 AS Company3
FROM (
  SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(SumHouseholds1) AS Company1  
  FROM (  
      SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds1  
      FROM Business  
      JOIN Location  
      ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
      WHERE DBAName='Company1'  
  GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households)
) AS c1
JOIN (
  SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(SumHouseholds2) AS Company2  
  FROM (  
      SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds2  
      FROM Business  
      JOIN Location  
      ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
      WHERE DBAName='Company2'  
  GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households)
) AS c2
ON c1.ZIPCode = c2.ZIPCode
JOIN (
  SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(SumHouseholds3) AS Company3  
  FROM (  
      SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds3  
      FROM Business  
      JOIN Location  
      ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
      WHERE DBAName='Company3'  
  GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households)
) AS c3
ON c1.ZIPCode = c3.ZIPCode
```

But then even though now it works (i hope as i have not tested it at all) it is too heavy and hard to manage
Below solves this (still not tested at all but should work and should give you an idea at least)

```
SELECT
  ZIPCode,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company1' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company2' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company3' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company3
FROM (
  SELECT ZIPCode, DBAName, SUM(SumHouseholds1) AS Company
  FROM (  
      SELECT ZIPCode, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds  
      FROM Business  
      JOIN Location  
      ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
  GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households)
)
GROUP BY ZIPCode
```

> July 12, 2016 update based on more info in comments

```
SELECT
 ZIPCode,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company1' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company2' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company2,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company3' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company3
FROM (
 SELECT ZIPCode, DBAName, SUM(SumHouseholds) AS Company
 FROM (  
    SELECT ZIPCode, DBAName, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName) AS SumHouseholds  
    FROM Business  
    JOIN Location  
    ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.Market  
    GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households
 )
 GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode
)
GROUP BY ZIPCode
```

output is

```
ZIPCode Company1    Company2    Company3     
10001    5           5           5   
10016    8           8           8   
12345   17          17          17   
16420   10           0           0
```

> Further thoughts

Above "fix" is still totally relying on assumption that your logic is correct.

I do have filling it is not:

I think below adjustments make it corrected:

First - grouping by Household looks extremely fishy and after reviewing your notes I think you need below

```
SELECT
  ZIPCode,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company1' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company2' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company3' THEN Company ELSE 0 END) AS Company3
FROM (  
  SELECT ZIPCode, DBAName, SUM(Households) AS Company  
  FROM (
    SELECT Market, DBAName 
    FROM AS Business 
    GROUP BY Market, DBAName
  ) AS Business
  JOIN Location  
  ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.Market  
  GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode
)
GROUP BY ZIPCode
```

Which in turn  - can be further simplified to

```
SELECT
  ZIPCode,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company1' THEN Households ELSE 0 END) AS Company1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company2' THEN Households ELSE 0 END) AS Company2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DBAName='Company3' THEN Households ELSE 0 END) AS Company3
FROM (  
  SELECT Market, DBAName 
  FROM Business 
  GROUP BY Market, DBAName
) AS Business
JOIN Location  
ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.Market  
GROUP BY ZIPCode
```

> Somehow I feel - The last query is what you are looking for!

But it is still an option that I just don't know some specifics of your real - most likely more complicated - use case, so in this case your original logic might be correct

Comment: Thanks again - both versions return a "SELECT clause has mix of aggregations 'Company[3]' and fields [...] without GROUP BY clause" error due to the Company - both are strings in the source tables, but maybe the Company[1/2/3] fields' data types need to be defined somehow in the query.

Comment: first version is EXACTLY your initial query just joined three times on zipcode - if your original code really works (which i asked you few times) that one should also work unless you are modifying it somehow. If further help needed you should provide some input data example and output!

Comment: Thanks - here are notes, input data and output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lab1eigzefld94p/stackoverflow.zip

Comment: do you still need help on this or this is just as FYI?

Comment: I'm still stumped on the issue mentioned in queries.txt of the .zip file - the field 'DBAName' isn't found unless the window function 'OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode, DBAName)' is removed. Do any options come to mind for making an alias of DBAName to avoid the 'not found' error? Any help would be great!

Comment: got it. will try to check this again later today. LA time :o)

Comment: ok. that was quite simple. a) missing DBAName in subselect with over and b) extra field (household) in group by of the same select. see updatet answer with working query. why you were waiting for so long with following up? :o)

Comment: The simplified one works perfectly - molodets, many thanks! Sorry for the delay between comments while moving between cities. The Households GROUP BY was indeed unnecessary once the CASE statements were added.